# Delphi CreateOleObject events

Tags: delphi, events, com, late-binding, createoleobject

There is a code:

```
var 
myobject: OleVariant;
begin
 myobject := CreateOleObject('SomeNamespace.SomeClass');
end;
```

This COM object has events (for example OnClick). How should I connect to these events without importing TLB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are working with COM late-binding, so do you need write a lot of code to handle events. this task is not difficult if you know COM, basically do you need follow these steps.

- Create a new object(class) derived from [`TInterfacedObject`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TInterfacedObject) that implements
  `IDispatch`
- implement the `Invoke()` function of your new class
- Query for the connection point container ([`IConnectionpointContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683857%28VS.85%29.aspx)) and desired connection point.
- sink the connection point using [`IConnectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692476%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- finally execute the [`IConnectionPoint.Advise()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678815%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) using your implementation of
  the `IDispatch`

you can found examples of this implementation on these links

- <strike>[How to use an objects event created using createoleobject](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_20418739.html)</strike>
- <strike>[Delphi 5 running powerpoint (example using a late binding object with events)](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22000475.html)</strike>
- [Delphi 5 running powerpoint](http://delphi.xcjc.net/viewthread.php?tid=39712&extra=page%3D30) (example using a late binding object with events)

try out these links for more info about COM, late-binding and events

- [Automation in Delphi COM Programming](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=130494&seqNum=5)
- [Supporting automation events in Delphi](http://www.gtro.com/delphi/comevents_e.php)